# Building Boost.Thread without interruption

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

How can I build boost.thread without default interruption point. I think that my application crash in a predefined interruption points. I'm using boost 1.53.0 with msvc10

I've the following code

```
class IOController {
public:
    IOController() { mThread = boost::thread( boost::bind( &IOController::poll, this ) ); }
    ~IOController() {mThread.interrupt(); mThread.join() }

    void doA() { boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock( mMutex);  }

private:
    void ICanThrow()
    {
        try
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock( mMutex); 
            callFunctionWithSleepFor(); // calling function that can throw and use boost::sleep_for
        }
        catch( boost::system_error&) {}
        catch( std::exception& ) {}
        catch ( ... ) { /* APPLICATION CRASH. */ }
    }
    // this is a thread: mThread = boost::thread(&IOController::poll, this) on ctor
    void poll()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            callFunctionWithSleepFor( );            
            this_thread::sleep_for( some_time );
        }
    }
boost::mutex mMutex;
boost::thread mThread;
};
```

Now I've the main thread that is calling that is calling doA in a very intensive way, and the class is polling on another thread. But sometimes I caght an exception in ICanThrow in the catch (...). I've no idea why this happen. But happen always from poll() thread.

Now I want try to build Boost without DONT_PROVIDE_INTERRUPTIONS. Does someone have some suggest?

Comment: Maybe in the dctor of IOController, mThread.interrupt cause ICanThrow() to launch an exception (boost::thread_interrupted that is not deriving from std::exception) in a point where is the statment boost::this_thread::sleep_for() (ICanThrow call function that has this statment). The exception is so caught from ICanThrow( ) in the caght( ... ). But this cause poll() to don't interrupt. Is it possible

Comment: Most likely you get a crash unrelated to interruptions. `boost::thread_interrupted` *is* derived from `std::exception`. You can use `disable_interruption` facility to disable interruptions fot current thread: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.disable_interruption

Comment: class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE thread_interrupted {}; thread_interrupted doesn't derive from anything (fortunatly). if thread_interrupted derives frome exception we can wrongly capture the wrong exception (as I have done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html. You can disable thread interruption with the disable_interruption class. I haven't used it myself, but it looks like if you instantiate *disable_interruption*, interruptions should be disabled until the *disable_interruption* object goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the destructor of IOController call `mThread.interrupt()` a function elsewere that is using sleep_for throw the exception. this exception is caght in the `caught(...)` but relly is just `boost::thread_interrupted` a class non deriving from anything.
The problem now is that `thread_interrupted` is not caght in the poll method so application is blocked on `mThread.join()`